# Shell script curl REST API - quoting issues

Tags: bash, shell, curl

```
curl -X DELETE -d '{"ruleid": "${value}"}' 'http://192.168.0.12:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json'
```

This command can't run correctly.
I don't know how to  handle this value parameter.  How to use the quotes?

```
#! /bin/bash
#  delete a firewall rule
value=x
if [ $1 != "" ]; then
value=$1
echo "$value"
curl -X DELETE -d '{"ruleid": "${value}"}'     http://192.168.0.12:8080/wm/firewall/rules/json
exit 0

else
    echo "no parameter "
    exit 0
fi
```

Comment: A helpful post here: [Difference between single and double quotes in Bash](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42082956/6862601)

Answer (score 3):

This example is a nightmare of quoting, but here is the correct syntax:

```
  curl -X DELETE -d '{"ruleid": "'"$value"'"}'
#                                ||      |
# here we close the single quote +|      + the same applies for closing 
#                                 |
#      here we open double quotes +
```

You should enclose everything in single quotes, except for the variable that is double quoted.

An alternative would be

```
curl -X DELETE -d "{\"ruleid\": \"$value\"}"
```